# A record exist only in Extension table, but not in the Base table

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I came across a weird situation:

I found a record that only exist in the entity's extension table in the DB, **but doesn't appear in the entity's base table**?

How is it possible?
Is there another optional reason beside the one of someone deleting the record directly from the base table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Screen shots please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other optional reasons, someone deleted manually the record from the base table